# How to set Progressbar / Span witdh using css

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, width

I'm currently facing a bug that won't let me set the width of the progress bar to anything other than 100%, but I know it's possible.I don't know if it's because I'm using too many classes (if that's the case) or if I have a syntax error, but most likely I have something wrong in my html code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="skill__content">
    <div class="skills__data">
        <div class="skills__titles ">
            <h3 class="skills__name">CSS</h3>
            <span class="skills__number">50%</span>
        </div>
        <div class="skills__bar">
            <span class="skills__percentage skills__css"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="skills__data">
    <div class="skills__titles ">
        <h3 class="skills__name">JS</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="skills__bar">
        <span class="skills__percentage skills__js"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*==================== VARIABLES CSS ====================*/
:root {
    --header-height: 3rem;

    /*========== Colors ==========*/
    /* Change favorite color */
    --hue-color: 255; /*Purple 250 - Green 142 - Blue 230 - Pink 340*/

    /* HSL color mode */
    --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
    --first-color-second: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
    --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 57%, 53%);
    --first-color-lighter: hsl(var(--hue-color), 92%, 85%);
    --title-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 15%);
    --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 45%);
    --text-color-light: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 65%);
    --input-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 70%, 96%);
    --body-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 60%, 99%);
    --container-color: #fff;
    --scroll-bar-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 12%, 90%);
    --scroll-thumb-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 12%, 80%);

    /*========== Font and typography ==========*/
    --body-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

    /* .5rem = 8px, 1rem = 16px, 1.5rem = 24px ... */
    --big-font-size: 2rem;
    --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
    --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
    --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
    --normal-font-size: .938rem;
    --small-font-size: .813rem;
    --smaller-font-size: .75rem;

    /*========== Font weight ==========*/
    --font-medium: 500;
    --font-semi-bold: 600;

    /*========== Margenes Bottom ==========*/
    /* .25rem = 4px, .5rem = 8px, .75rem = 12px ... */
    --mb-0-25: .25rem;
    --mb-0-5: .5rem;
    --mb-0-75: .75rem;
    --mb-1: 1rem;
    --mb-1-5: 1.5rem;
    --mb-2: 2rem;
    --mb-2-5: 2.5rem;
    --mb-3: 3rem;

    /*========== z index ==========*/
    --z-tooltip: 10;
    --z-fixed: 100;
    --z-modal: 1000;
}

.skills__container{
  row-gap: 0;
}

.skills__header{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2-5);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.skills__icon,
.skills__arrow{
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__icon{
  margin-right: var(--mb-0-75);
}

.skills__titles{
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
}

.skills__subtitle{
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.skills__arrow{
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: .6s;
}

.skills__list{
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
  padding-left: 2.7rem;
}

.skills__titles{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-5);
}

.skills__name{
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

.skills__bar,
.skills__percentage{
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

.skills__bar{
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__percentage{
  display: block;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__css{
  width: 50%;
}
```

i tried getting help from ChatGPT and watching a youtube tutorial but nothing seemed to work. Any help is appreciated.

**This is the desired look**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if this suits your need.

```css
/*==================== VARIABLES CSS ====================*/

:root {
  --header-height: 3rem;
  /*========== Colors ==========*/
  /* Change favorite color */
  --hue-color: 255;
  /*Purple 250 - Green 142 - Blue 230 - Pink 340*/
  /* HSL color mode */
  --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-second: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 57%, 53%);
  --first-color-lighter: hsl(var(--hue-color), 92%, 85%);
  --title-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 15%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 45%);
  --text-color-light: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 65%);
  --input-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 70%, 96%);
  --body-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 60%, 99%);
  --container-color: #fff;
  --scroll-bar-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 12%, 90%);
  --scroll-thumb-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 12%, 80%);
  /*========== Font and typography ==========*/
  --body-font: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  /* .5rem = 8px, 1rem = 16px, 1.5rem = 24px ... */
  --big-font-size: 2rem;
  --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
  --normal-font-size: 0.938rem;
  --small-font-size: 0.813rem;
  --smaller-font-size: 0.75rem;
  /*========== Font weight ==========*/
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;
  /*========== Margenes Bottom ==========*/
  /* .25rem = 4px, .5rem = 8px, .75rem = 12px ... */
  --mb-0-25: 0.25rem;
  --mb-0-5: 0.5rem;
  --mb-0-75: 0.75rem;
  --mb-1: 1rem;
  --mb-1-5: 1.5rem;
  --mb-2: 2rem;
  --mb-2-5: 2.5rem;
  --mb-3: 3rem;
  /*========== z index ==========*/
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
  --z-modal: 1000;
}

.skills__container {
  row-gap: 0;
}

.skills__header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2-5);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.skills__icon,
.skills__arrow {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__icon {
  margin-right: var(--mb-0-75);
}

.skills__titles {
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
}

.skills__subtitle {
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.skills__arrow {
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.skills__list {
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
  padding-left: 2.7rem;
}

.skills__titles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-5);
}

.skills__name {
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

.skills__bar,
.skills__percentage {
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.skills__bar {
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  /*   display: inline-block;
  width: 50%; */
}

.skills__percentage {
  display: block;
  background-color: var(--first-color-lighter);
}

.skills__css {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(first-color-lighter);
}
```

```html
<div class="skill__content">
  <div class="skills__data">
    <div class="skills__titles ">
      <h3 class="skills__name">CSS</h3>
      <span class="skills__number">50%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="skills__bar">
      <span class="skills__percentage skills__css"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="skills__data">
  <div class="skills__titles ">
    <h3 class="skills__name">JS</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="skills__bar">
    <span class="skills__percentage skills__js"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: almost, i need it for every Skill (Language i added) your answer would set them all to 50% i need it to be able to set for every specific skill